# How can I shared a execution context between a group of threads?

Tags: c#, multithreading, ioc-container

In Foo method, I create some task and I want to set a context in the main thread and access to it from other threads, is there any way I shared a context between my main thread and other threads than created in the main thread? I don't want to pass context to other threads and my preference is to set the context in a single point like in a custom lifestyle in IOC container for my execution context

```
public class IUserContext
{
    string UserName {get;}
    string Token {get;}
}

public void Foo()
{//I set the context data before calling the method
    foreach(...) {
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>method1);
    }

    void method1()
    {
         // context is null
         var context = Container.Resolve<IUserContext>();
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the **concrete** type of `IUserContext`?  Entity Framework is not multi-connection safe.

Comment: @ErikPhilips UserContext fill in WCF begin request and  I get Token from request header and get user data from cache by token, then I want access to  usercontext in method1

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
public class IUserContext
{
    public string  UserName 
    {
        get
        {
            return "user";
        }
    }
    public string Token 
    {
        get
        {
            return "token";
        }
    }
}

public class Program
{
    public static IUserContext context = new IUserContext();

    public static void Main()
    {

        for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) 
        {            
            Task.Factory.StartNew(() => method1());
        }
    }

    public static void method1()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("I'm task #" + Task.CurrentId + " and I work with user " + context.UserName + " that have token " + context.Token);
    }    
}
```

But you always need to remember about that different threads can operate with shared objects simultaneously, so if you want to use objects that threads can modify you must remember about [synchronizing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/threading/synchronizing-data-for-multithreading)

Answer (score 0):

You could use an **Static** method but be sure to apply a singleton pattern, or save the concurrency problem by any way

```
public static void Foo()
{   
   //Singleton start
   private static ReadOnly Foo instance;
   private Foo() {}

   public static Foo Instance
   {
        get{
          if(instance == null){
             instance = new Foo();
             }
             return instance;
             }
   }
   //Singleton end

   public static void method1()
   {
        // context is null
        var context = Container.Resolve<IUserContext>();
   }
}
```

Then you can call this method inside each task

take a look for a singleton instance
https://codeburst.io/singleton-design-pattern-implementation-in-c-62a8daf3d115

Comment: Idon't want it shared between all threads.I want it shared between the main thread that call foo method a other thread that create in the foo method(group of related threads), if another process call foo method it must be shared between that's group of threads